# psplash-write does not work when psplash is started from the init script (PID=1)

Tags: linux, bash, yocto, nvidia-jetson

I have integrated psplash to a custom Yocto layer for NVIDIA Jetson Nano. I want to run psplash from the very first init script (PID=1). The reason is to cover the time spent by systemd to load unit and service files. I have added `init=/bin/newinit.sh` to the Linux kernel parameters. Here is the content of the `/bin/newinit.sh` that replaces my `/sbin/init`.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/psplash &
/bin/psplashanimator.sh &
exec /sbin/init
```

Here is the content of the `/bin/psplashanimator.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sleep 0.1 && /usr/bin/psplash-write "PROGRESS 50"
```

I made sure that `psplash-write` is not called by any other process by disabling the systemd daemons (psplash-start, psplash-systemd). Yet, I can't update the progress bar by using these scripts. Psplash is displayed nicely, but nothing on the progress bar.
If I move `/bin/sleep 0.1 && /usr/bin/psplash-write "PROGRESS 50"` into the `/bin/newinit.sh` before `exec`, it works fine; but it blocks the main execution of the init script.

All in all, if I start the psplash in a custom init script, psplash-write only works before the exec is called. I can't figure out why that is and how to fix that.

If there is a simple solution or rationale as to why this wouldn't work, I would kindly appreciate your guidance.

**NOTE1:** Note that conventional way of updating psplash with systemd services (`psplash-systemd.service`) work fine when psplash is started using `psplash-start.service`, I get progress bar updates.

**NOTE2:** Psplash uses framebuffer driver and FIFO.

**NOTE3:** Related source files: [psplash.c](https://github.com/g0hl1n/psplash/blob/master/psplash.c) [psplash-write.c](https://github.com/g0hl1n/psplash/blob/master/psplash-write.c)

**NOTE4:** Current systemd execution (to let you see if I am missing something that must be ready before running psplash)

[image: Systemd Execution]

Comment: Have you figured out why? I think I am dealing with the same issue.

Comment: @AdamLee Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure this out and solved my issue using some non-efficient workaround, as the solution was not crucial to my application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about psplash and systemd, but it might be the case you need to have something like this in your environment to control psplash:

export TMPDIR=/mnt/.psplash